# What cells don't have a primary cilium?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, cilia

It is [often stated](http://www.nature.com/nrm/journal/v12/n4/abs/nrm3085.html) that most cells in the human body have a primary cilium.

Which ones don't? For which cells is it unknown?

Comment: Hi, if you found my answer acceptable, it would be a nice gesture to show this by marking it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @leonardo, but I was asking about unciliated cells in particular. I'll wait to see if anyone can provide a more authoritative answer saying there are none, or an example of cells with no cilia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, by and large, most animal and plant cells have primary cilia. To quote from [this open access paper](http://www.landesbioscience.com/journals/organogenesis/article/28910/):

> ".[..] organisms that form cilia have a basal body or centriole-like structure as their microtubule-organizing center, whereas those that do not [e.g., yeast, higher plants] use morphologically distinct structures for organization of their microtubule cytoskeleton."

Other cases where cells lack primary cilia are when they possess motile cilia (e.g., sperm are mono-ciliated, respiratory epithelia are multi-cilliated).

1. [Fry AM, Leaper MJ, Bayliss R. The primary cilium: Guardian of organ development and homeostasis. Organogenesis. 2014 Jan 1;10(1):62-68. Epub 2014 Apr 17.](http://www.landesbioscience.com/journals/organogenesis/article/28910/)